# How do I retrieve cookies from the cookie space used by AMF?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I have a flex app that uses AMF to talk to a Spring Java backend.  How do I get the values of cookies that have been set by the server and are being sent back by AMF?

Comment: Could you explain your goals please?

Comment: I'd like to gain a better understanding of how AMF uses cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no difference between cookies that are set during AMF request and normal web requests from the browser. So you can access those cookies with a little bit of JavaScript and ExternalInterface.

You can find code on how to do that right here on stackoverflow:

- [is it possible to value store cookies in Flash or Flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689215/is-it-possible-to-value-store-cookies-in-flash-or-flex)
- [Accessing browser cookies from Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523633/accessing-browser-cookies-from-flex)

EDIT: To answer your second question... AMF is not a transport protocol. It's just a binary protocol to transfer data on top of tranport protocols like HTTP or HTTPS. If you take a look at the specifications of [AMF0](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/1114283/amf0_spec_121207.pdf) and [AMF3](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/1114283/amf3_spec_05_05_08.pdf) you won't find any mention of cookies.

So, no AMF doesn't use cookies (it doesn't even know about cookies), but the underlying protocols (HTTP, HTTPS) can use them (for example to exchange session IDs). You can take a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) if you want to know more about HTTP Cookies.

Comment: Does AMF use javascript to get and set these cookie values?

Comment: AFAIK the Flash Player uses the browser for it's HTTP requests and the AMF protocol uses HTTP... So there is no need for the Flash Player to use JavaScript or whatnot to get/set cookies since the browser does this all automatically. I haven't tested it but I'm pretty sure that all Set-Cookie headers in AMF responses are ignored if you disable the support for cookies in your browser.